# How to add markers to each page with the number of the first and last numbered environment/equation which appear in the page?

Tags: fancyhdr, tufte, book-design

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the following dictionary-like functionality:

> Add markers to each page with the number of the first and last numbered environment/equation which appear in the page.

Thus, if the first numbered environment/equation in a page is 2.34 and the last one 2.39 I would like to print in the footer, say,

> 2.34--2.39

I am using `tufte-book` which uses `fancyhdr`, **and all of my numbered environments/equations share the same counter.**

I looked into [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/dictionary) dictionary template to see if I could figure out what to do but that did't go so well.

P.S. I do not include a MWE since I have absolutely no idea where to start. Pointers are also welcome :)

**EDIT**

Here is a MWE with what I have tried so far. I am trying to print the value of the `equation` counter as soon as the header is typeset, and storing it for later use.

Sorry for the lengthy code, but one needs many pages to see that the problems with the values at different pages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{firstequation}

\newcounter{lastequation}

\newcommand{\myeqnmarker}{%
  \setcounter{lastequation}{\theequation-3}%
  \thefirstequation--\thelastequation%
  \setcounter{firstequation}{\value{equation}-2}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[LE]{\myeqnmarker}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\myeqnmarker}%

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not so easy, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added a MWE with what I can do so far. I feel I am close to getting it right, but I don't get whats going on with the counter when the page changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the improved version at the bottom, as well as some explanations.

A preliminary version so far -- it seems to work, but the page number should not be changed, so this is a bottleneck at the moment.

I will add some explanations later on, trying to improve the code. 
It's not failsafe if a page does not have equations at all!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_equation_number

\ior_new:N \l_enr_file

\newcommand{\equationnumber}[1]{%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \seq_gput_right:NV \l_equation_number {\l_tmpa_tl}
}

\newcommand{\grabequationnumbers}{%
  \ior_open:Nn \l_enr_file {\jobname.enr}
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_enr_file {\equationnumber{##1}}
  \ior_close:N \l_enr_file
}

\newcommand{\showlist}{%
  \seq_use:Nn \l_equation_number {\par}
}


\newcommand{\geteqrange}[1]{%
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_equation_number {%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {;} {##1}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
    \int_compare:nNnT {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}} = {\l_tmpb_int} {%
      \seq_gput_right:NV \l_tmpa_seq {\l_tmpb_tl}
    }
  }
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_seq {%
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}}
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}\space --\space  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff




\makeatletter


\let\latex@@refstepcounter\refstepcounter

\newwrite\equationfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.enr}{%
  \grabequationnumbers
  }{}
  \immediate\openout\equationfile=\jobname.enr
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\equationfile%
}

\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{%
  \latex@@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{equation}{%
    \immediate\write\equationfile{\the\numexpr\value{page};\theequation}%
  }{}
}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\geteqrange{\the\numexpr\value{page}-0}}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 
\end{align}

\blindtext[5]\clearpage

\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 
\end{align}
\blindtext

\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \\
\end{align}



\blindtext[3]

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

**Update**, using safer `\label`s to equations:

This is the basic idea: Provide an automatic label for each equation that is numbered (i.e. there's a `\refstepcounter` hook, using a 'unique' `\label`, which has the correct page information then. 
This information is read in again with `\getpagerefnumber` and `\getrefnumber` (package `refcount`) and stored to a special file which is processed using `expl3` methods in order to get the current `equation` range of the page.

A single equation is displayed as a single equation number then, a page with no (numbered) equation will have an empty footer slot for this.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{totalequations}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{equation}{totalequations}  % Step the equations to get the full equation number

% Personal display style
% #1 -> first equation 'number'
% #2 -> second equation 'number'
\newcommand{\equationrangeformat}[2]{%
  #1 $\longleftrightarrow$ #2% 
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_equation_number

\ior_new:N \l_enr_file

% Mapping function
\newcommand{\equationnumber}[1]{%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \seq_gput_right:NV \l_equation_number {\l_tmpa_tl}
}

% Load the stored equation numbers
\newcommand{\grabequationnumbers}{%
  \ior_open:Nn \l_enr_file {\jobname.enr}
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_enr_file {\equationnumber{##1}}
  \ior_close:N \l_enr_file
}

\newcommand{\geteqrange}[1]{%
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_equation_number {%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {;} {##1}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
    \int_compare:nNnT {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}} = {\l_tmpb_int} {%
      \seq_gput_right:NV \l_tmpa_seq {\l_tmpb_tl}
    }
  }
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_seq {%
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}}
    % Check whether there's only one equation marker
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int} = {1} {
      \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {} % Just display the one-element sequence
    } {%
      \equationrangeformat{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}}%
    }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff




\makeatletter

% We need to hook into `\refstepcounter` since this is increasing the equation number 
\let\latex@@refstepcounter\refstepcounter
\newwrite\file@equation

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % Prevent loading errors by checking for existence first, read the information then.
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.enr}{%
    \grabequationnumbers%
  }{}
  % Open the equation number file for writing again, for update purposes
  \immediate\openout\file@equation=\jobname.enr
}



\newcommand{\eqmarkerlabel}{%
  eqmarker:\number\value{totalequations}%
}

\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{%
  \latex@@refstepcounter{#1}
  \ifstrequal{#1}{equation}{%
    \label{\eqmarkerlabel}% Generate an automatic label
    \immediate\write\file@equation{\getpagerefnumber{\eqmarkerlabel};\getrefnumber{\eqmarkerlabel}}% Store the label information to another file
  }{}%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\file@equation% 
}


\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\geteqrange{\number\value{page}}}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 
\end{align}

\blindtext[5]

\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 \\
  E=mc^2 
\end{align}
\blindtext

\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 
\end{align}



\blindtext[2]

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\chapter{Foobar}
\blindtext[2]

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{align*}
  E=mc^2 
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The page style is something very tricky here!

Comment: A better approach would use two or more runs to make the equation number saving stable.

Comment: It is working almost as expected! Sometimes the numbering is off by one, but it is definitely more accurate than my solution.

Comment: @Gustavo: I've to think about the whole stuff again. The page counter is a tricky `friend`. And I've to use `tufte` of course.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am not able to tinker with your solution as I have no idea what is going on in there... :)

Comment: @Gustavo: It's `expl3` syntax, to  get an easy access to the page/equation number pairs. As I said, I've to restructure the code

Comment: @Gustavo: I've provided a better version

Comment: Great! For my purposes it is not a big deal that the page number cannot be changed; about pages without equations, that should not be a problem either. Thanks again!

Comment: @Gustavo: I don't understand. Why do want to the change the page number?