# Setting marks automatically when a counter is incremented

Tags: counters, ntheorem

I want to create a dictionary-like header, where on the top left of the even page and the top right of the odd page equation numbers will be shown: on the top left is the equation number of the first equation appearing on the page and on the top right is the last equation number.

I know I can achieve this with `\marks` and in particular the `emarks` package. Right now my "solution" requires manually pushing the new equation number onto the mark like

```
\marksthe{EqNumTracker}{\theequation}
```

everytime I write a new equation, which seems to be less than ideal.

A further complication is that the `equation` counter is also touched by some other things (for example, using `ntheorem` I've requested that the theorems count on the same counter).

**Question**: what is the best way to automatically "mark" the equation number everytime the `equation` counter is incremented?

---

A minimal possibly working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{emarks}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Pagestyle using the marks. 
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{wwwfancy}{\headrule%
    \setmarks{chapter}{section}
    \sethead[\thefirstmarks{www@equation@mark}]%
        [][]%
        {\footnotesize\slshape\ifthechapter{\chaptertitlename\ %
        \thechapter.\ \chaptertitle}{}}{}%
        {\thebotmarks{www@equation@mark}}%
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{wwwfancy}

% Redefining refstepcounter
\let\www@old@refstepcounter\refstepcounter
\def\refstepcounter#1{%
    \www@old@refstepcounter{#1}%
    \marksthecs{www@#1@mark}{the#1}}
\makeatother

% Define a theorem style
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremindent0cm
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}

\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{thm}\label{testref}
\lipsum[7]
\end{thm}

\lipsum[8-12]

A reference \thref{testref}. 

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Is there something I should watch out for?

(Note, in the above I defined a mark for *every* counter used, effectively. I think 32,768 is probably enough to do that... but I would also welcome an improvement that allows me to just track `equation` and nothing else.)

Comment: One can think to modify `\stepcounter` to do something more when receiving the `equation` counter as argument, but having a small example is better: if you use `hyperref`, for instance, a solution must take this into account and timing of redefinitions is crucial.

Comment: @egreg: I included a first attempt (modified `\refstepcounter` instead). It _seems_ to work. What is the potential problem with `hyperref` that you are thinking of?

Comment: I've done something similar recently in another question ... looking for it...

Comment: Since `hyperref` modifies `\stepcounter`/`\refstepcounter`, it's important to do the change at the right time.

Comment: Something like here, perhaps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307688/how-to-add-markers-to-each-page-with-the-number-of-the-first-and-last-numbered-e ?

Comment: I would have used the everypage package to check \theequation at the end of page and write the header.  The tricky bit is the first page when the counter gets reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code by the O.P. was already working, also with `hyperref`, but it placed a mark every time a counter was refstepped.

I've place some `expl3` code to 'register' counter names in a sequence that should be tracked for convenience and perform a check in the redefined `\refstepcounter` command that only the relevant mark will be placed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{emarks}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_williewong_counter_seq
\newcommand{\RegisterMarkCounters}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_williewong_counter_seq {#1}
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l_williewong_counter_seq
}
\newcommand{\IsInMarkListT}[2]{%
  \seq_if_in:NnT \l_williewong_counter_seq {#1} {#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Pagestyle using the marks. 
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{wwwfancy}{\headrule%
    \setmarks{chapter}{section}
    \sethead[\thefirstmarks{www@equation@mark}]%
        [][]%
        {\footnotesize\slshape\ifthechapter{\chaptertitlename\ %
        \thechapter.\ \chaptertitle}{}}{}%
        {\thebotmarks{www@equation@mark}}%
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{wwwfancy}





\RegisterMarkCounters{equation}

\let\www@old@refstepcounter\refstepcounter
\def\refstepcounter#1{%
  \www@old@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \IsInMarkListT{#1}{\marksthecs{www@#1@mark}{the#1}}
}


\makeatother

% Define a theorem style
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremindent0cm
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}

\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{Foo}

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}


\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}


\begin{thm}\label{testref}
  \lipsum[7]
\end{thm}

\lipsum[8-12]

A reference \thref{testref}. 

\lipsum[1-4]


\begin{thm}\label{othertestref}
\lipsum[7]
\end{thm}

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}



\lipsum[8-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Slowly slowly I am getting used to reading expl3 code. Question about the data structure: what is a `\seq`? Is it ordered? Are entries unique? (In the sense of "what happens if I `\RegisterMarkCounters` twice the same counter?") In actually using it I would probably have to skip the `\typeout` since it will really add a lot of lines to the log files.

Comment: I will add some explanations later on

Comment: @WillieWong: Changed...

Comment: @WillieWong: As `\seq` is a ordered list,but the entries are not unique by default, so it's not a set. You can remove duplicates with `\seq_remove_duplicates:N`

Answer (score 2):

We can add a hook at `\stepcounter` using `etoolbox`. Without `amsmath` the patch could be

```
\apptocmd{\stepcounter}{\csname action@#1\endcsname}{}{}
```

but `amsmath` already does a change.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{emarks}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% add a hook to \stepcounter
\patchcmd{\stepcounter}
  {\fi}
  {\csname action@#1\endcsname\fi}
  {}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definecounteraction}[2]{\@namedef{action@#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

% Pagestyle using the marks. 
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{wwwfancy}{\headrule%
    \setmarks{chapter}{section}
    \sethead[\thefirstmarks{www@equation@mark}]%
        [][]%
        {\footnotesize\slshape\ifthechapter{\chaptertitlename\ %
        \thechapter.\ \chaptertitle}{}}{}%
        {\thebotmarks{www@equation@mark}}%
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{wwwfancy}

\definecounteraction{equation}{%
  \typeout{=== Stepping equation ===}%
  \marksthe{www@equation@mark}{\theequation}%
}

% Define a theorem style
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremindent0cm
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}

\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{thm}\label{testref}
\lipsum[7]
\end{thm}

\lipsum[8-12]

A reference \thref{testref}. 

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both great answers! I flipped a coin.

Comment: @WillieWong Which fell on the wrong side. `;-)`